# Meaning of directory redirection using dot operator

Tags: 12.04

I know that `.` means current directory and `..` means one directory up from my current directory but when I put `/` and `..` after I got confused what that meant.

please explain this a bit.

In shot what does `../..` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 directories up ,  / is part of the path, so just as

/home/your_username

.. = one directory up

../.. = two directories up

../../.. three - etc

See also relative vs absolute path

If you start from / , it is an absolute path, /home/your_user for example

If you start from your current directory, without a / in front, the path is relative to your current directory. So , in your home directory, Desktop == /home-your_user/Desktop.

See http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/07/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix.html or similar

Comment: I still did not understand the latter ..

Comment: each pair of dots = one directory up , so ../../.. = 3